# contact form sending twice

Tags: javascript, php, forms, contacts

My contact form is sending emails twice and I cannot figure out why..
When I submit the form the sending message and succes message shows up twice, also I receive the email twice.

You can find the form on: [www.dev-kevin.compoint.be/ctrl+/](http://www.dev-kevin.compoint.be/ctrl+/)

I can't find the problem...

form:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Naam" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="tel" name="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefoon" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Bericht" required></textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Verstuur</button>
</form>
```

sendemail.php:

```
<?php
$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$from = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['tel'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to = "kevin@compoint.be";

$mensaje = "Naam: $name \nEmail: $from \nTelefoon: $subject \nBericht: $message";

$pagetitle = "Bericht via de website";

$from = "FROM: Website <info@ctrl+.be>\r\n";


mail($to, $pagetitle, $mensaje, $from);

die();
```

Javascript:

```
// Contact form
    var form = $('#main-contact-form');
    form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    beforeSend: function(){
    form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email versturen...</p>').fadeIn() );
    }
    }).done(function(data){
    form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Uw bericht is succesvol verzonden. Wij nemen zo spoedig mogelijk contact met u op.</p>').delay(1000).fadeOut();
    }); 
    });
```

Comment: The form has the Action and submit button, when the submit is clicked this execute the sendemail.php ( 1st render ) and in the javascript file when the form.submit is triggered it will trigger the sendemail.php ( 2nd render ) again

Comment: So what do I change to make this send and show only once? I tried to remove stuff but it keeps showing the succesfully sent message twice, even when it doesn't send the mails..

Comment: Simply add a `return false;` at the end of the `submit` handler